# Link to tag redirecting to top of page when navigating from within page

Tags: html, menu, tags, anchor

I have a drop down menu which I include on all my pages using php. On this menu I am using anchors to navigate to various divs on a single page. It is very simple code, anchors with tags in the href, no JavaScript.

```
            <a href="test.php#test">Test</a>
```

navigates to

```
            <h2 id="test">Test</h2>
```

If I am navigating to the page this works fine. If I am already on the page it goes to the tag then redirects back to the page without the tag (i.e. goes from test.php#test to test.php). What is causing this behavior and how do I fix it?

Comment: You might consider sharing some code with us.

Answer (score 0):

If you had provided more code then it would have been more helpful. But I am just guessing here what the problem is. You can add the following javascript to your page:

```
$("a[href^=#]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  history.pushState({}, "", this.href); 
});
```

What this does is target all hash-links and prevent their default behavior and change the URL. But without seeing more of your code, its hard to tell if it'd work. You can also interchangeably use `replaceState`, which would change the URL without adding an entry to the browser history. Code borrowed from [here](http://css-tricks.com/on-target/).